# OpenSSL encoding errors while converting cer to pem

Tags: linux, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I`m trying to convert the .cer file to .pem through openssl, the command is:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certnew.cer -out ymcert.pem
```

and that's the errors I`m getting:

```
unable to load certificate
140735105180124:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1319:
140735105180124:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:381:Type=X509
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your `cer` file is already in `pem` form. Read http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/Error-converting-from-cer-to-pem-td2179.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had this problem also. Just rename the CER to PEM was enough :)

Answer (score 43):

Like [explained by ssl.com](https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them), a .cer file can be either in `der` or `pem` encoding. If it is in der encoding, you'll need to do conversion like you have tried, but if it is already in pem encoding, no conversion is necessary and you get the error you've got if you try - and you can just rename the file.

If you're unsure, it is good to know that .der is a binary format, whereas .pem is ascii one. If you echo the contents of your certificate out, a .pem file would look something like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEuTCCA6G[snip lots of chars]
XmCpajQ==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And a .der file would look like this:

```
0▒▒0▒▒▒@*▒H▒▒▒▒▒0
0▒▒1
    0   UUS10U
VeriSign, Inc.10U
                 VeriSign Trust Network1:08U
```

Answer (score 6):

I had same Problem then I have removed `-inform der` form the comment then it worked fine for me.

```
openssl x509 -in alpha.cer -out alpha.pem
```

Answer (score 1):

no need to convert the file from .cer to .pem you just need to use this command and desired result will be get
**openssl x509 -inform pem -in certificate.cer -pubkey -noout > certificate_publickey.pem**
it all depends on which encoding type used to generate the certificate as mentioned by @eis

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue with CRT format which give me error during converting to pem. I do same thing like L0g0ff and it works. Below more details.

1. I checked details of certificate:

   `openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -noout -text`
2. after changing extension to from certificate.crt to certificate.pem I get file in expected format:

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...........................
-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

Comment: changing the extension won't change the file format, so it was as expected to begin with.