# converting .cer to .pem returns error 'unable to load certificate'

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I got an email containing a cert, it looked something like:

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>
> MIIHE...
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----

I copy/pasted that into notepad and saved it as a .cer file.

What I need now is a .pfx file using this cert. From what I gather I need to first convert my .cer to a .pem.

I tried converting my .cer to a .pem but that only gave error:

> OpenSSL> x509 -inform der -in
> C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\cert.cer -out certificate.pem
>
> unable to load certificate 7320:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding
> routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:.\crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:1315:
> 7320:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested
> asn1 error:.\crypto\asn1\tasn_dec.c:379:Type=X509

I read some answers that also say just changing .cer to .pem is enough, but for me that does not seem to work at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenSSL encoding errors while converting cer to pem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191468/openssl-encoding-errors-while-converting-cer-to-pem)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your certificate is already in PEM format. Just rename it from `certificate.cer` to `certificate.pem`

Comment: Hmm, is there anyway I can test that this actually works? If I save it as a .pem my comp just treats it like a .txt file and opens it in notepad. But maybe that is intended. (i.e I cope/paste into notepad and save as .pem)

Comment: Use it. that's how you find out :)