# Apache SSL Converting itermediateCA.cer to crt with openssl

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl

Try to convert IntermidiateCA.cer to crt formmat for Apache but I couldn't. I use the following command below:

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in IntermediateCA.cer -out IntermediateCA.crt
```

This the error I got below

```
unable to load certificate
4276141236:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong 
tag:tasn_dec.c:1198:
 4276141236:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested 
asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:372:Type=X509
```

Kindly note the server is solaris 5.10

Comment: What version of openssl are you using?

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015 @MrGlass

Comment: Check to make sure you don’t have **any** leading or trailing whitespace around your certificate data. If that’s not it maybe one of these will help:
https://serverfault.com/questions/786328/error-in-converting-crt-certificate-to-pem   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191468/openssl-encoding-errors-while-converting-cer-to-pem

Comment: Try the links you provided I try the solution. But still get the same error

Comment: There really is no such thing as .cer format or .crt format because they are just file extensions, not formats. There are unfortunately many possibilities for what's inside the `IntermediateCA.cer` file but we have no way of knowing which it is.

Comment: Show the content of `IntermediateCA.cer`, it is public data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenSSL encoding errors while converting cer to pem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191468/openssl-encoding-errors-while-converting-cer-to-pem)

Comment: you're specifying "-inform DER" but your file is not in .der format, simple as that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two common certificate encoding types. If you can read the "----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----" then it's PEM encoded. If not, DER (binary) encoded. Trying to convert with the openssl x509 command specifying the wrong encoding will produce the error you got.

If certificate file is DER encoded (binary)

`openssl x509 -inform DER -in certificate.cer -out certificate.crt`

If certificate is PEM encoded (human readable)

`openssl x509 -inform PEM -in certificate.cer -out certificate.crt`