# X509Certificate is my cer file valid? getting private key not loaded

Tags: c#, ssl, openssl, x509certificate

Allow me to preface this by saying that I did browse other available posts on SO, and tried the suggested fixes, such as doing some of the suggested solutions such as:

- converting it to a pem file
  `openssl x509 -inform der -in mycer.cer -out mycer.pem`
- Seeing if the cert was in an odd format so trying to "fix it"
  `openssl x509 -inform DER -in ingagedcert.cer -out ingagedcert.crt`

etc.

None of those worked. I looked at my file (given to us by a client facing some issues with their SSO) in VS code and the format was `<X509Certificate>MIIFxT....</X509Certificate>`. This made me realize that the file is probably already in a .pem format more than likely (per: [OpenSSL encoding errors while converting cer to pem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191468/openssl-encoding-errors-while-converting-cer-to-pem)). However, it was missing the Begin and End cert lines. I've thus updated the file to be as follows:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIT....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Good stuff, this allowed me to bypass the "unable to find object" error. However, now, upon running it I encounter:

```
ComponentSpace.SAML2.Exceptions.SAMLSignatureException: 'Failed to generate XML signature.'
CryptographicException: Signing key is not loaded.
```

This blows up on the `Generate` call as the `PrivateKey` is null:

```
X509Certificate2 x509Certificate = LoadCertificate(certificatePath, password);
            SAMLMessageSignature.Generate(samlResponseXml, x509Certificate.PrivateKey, x509Certificate);
            IdentityProvider.SendSAMLResponseByHTTPPost(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, relayState, samlResponseXml, relayState);

If I were to run this SSL command to try to convert my .cer file (and the .pem file I was able to generate after fixing the format) 

`λ openssl pkcs12 -inkey ingagedcert.pem -in ingagedcert.cer -export -out ingagedcert.pfx` then it will also complain about a key.
```

unable to load private key
37072:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../openssl-1.1.1h/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

```
I am curious as to how would I verify that the .cer file that the user has provided is actually valid? I am not too familiar with SSO, certs, etc. so this is very much a learning experience for me.
```

Comment: You're undoubtedly only receiving the certificate, which is just a signed public key (and some other metadata).  In that case, you already either have the private key and know how to find it, or you don't have it and so can't sign things.  It vaguely sounds like you're trying to either verify the validity of a cert chain, or verify a signature already present in the file... but without more details it's hard to say how to get from where you are to where you want to be.

Comment: a CER file cannot contain a private key.

Comment: @DenisMicheal: *"a CER file cannot contain a private key"* - there is no "CER file". ".cer" is just a file extension which suggests some content but does not enforce it - it could contain anything with this name. There are various formats certificates can be stored. Some like PEM and PKCS#7 can actually include both (multiple) certificates and private key. But in this case the file only include the certificate, not the private key.

Comment: Well, yes, but commonly it contains just one certificate or possibly a chain. .pfx or .p12 is normally used for chains including an (encrypted) private key.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is simply that [an X509 certificate](https://rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) does **not** contain a private key; it only contains meta data, the public key that belongs to the keypair of the subject / owner of the certificate and of course a signature over that data.

Out of convenience *but against the principle of least surprise* the `X509Certificate2` class in .NET can also include the associated private key, which means that the certificate / private key pair can be used for signing or decryption - depending on the key usage specified within the certificate.

Generally these kind of key / certificate pairs (and their parent CA certificates) are contained in a PFX file, a format specified in [the PKCS#12 specifications](https://rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292).

---

[PEM has a very specific format](https://rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468), including - for instance - particular line endings after a certain amount of base 64 characters that represent the binary DER encoded certificate. What you are looking at instead is just the direct base 64 encoding of this certificate.

Comment: I see, so does this mean I need to decode the contents of my file and then turn that into a .pem file? Or do I need to go back to our customer support team and ask the user to provide me with the .pfx file instead of their .cer file? I assume there is no real way for me to convert the .cer to a .pfx? Apologies if these questions are novice

Comment: Also, would this be of any use to know that if I run the following: file myCer.cer, I get the following:
myCer.cer: ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators. Though running it on the .pem I made via some of the commands I've found whilst trying to solve this I get: myCer.pem: PEM certificate

Comment: Right, at this point I am quite confident the issue is with wht I was given. If I change x509Certificate.PrivateKey to just be RSA.Create(), it will go do my backend and try to process SSO. However, it then fails to initialize the certificate.

Comment: Yes, you should ask for a PFX. You cannot convert the .cer to a PFX that works as you're missing the private key.